# subprocess run искажает параметр. Как узнать что именно получается при запуске?

Tags: python, subprocess, ос

Я в python запускаю внешнюю программу с параметрами, используя функцию run модуля subprocess. Передаю туда первый параметр типа list. Но программа не запускается, т.к. subprocess искажает один параметр который является путём. Возникают ошибки типа "нет доступа к d:" или какие то другие, если я пробую экспериментировать с кавычками.

Как мне понять, какой конечный путь составляет subprocess, какой путь запускает в ОС? Сторонними средствами или как можно узнать это?

Comment: Внесите код в студию.

Comment: можно попробовать сделать составной вызов, типа `<program> <args> 2> <some_stderr_output_path>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заработало.

Решил упростить и уменьшить пример, чтобы внести код в студию, по просьбе [@AlexeyTen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363380/subprocess-run-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5/1363406#comment2419178_1363380). И этот упрощенный код заработал без ошибок.

Я использовал апострофы для обертки одного из параметров, который является путем и они портили результат. Убрал эти апострофы и все заработало.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).